# How to redirect an Express path to a port in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have several Node.JS apps in different ports:

- **app_a:8000**
- **app_b:8001**
- **app_c:8002**

Some of them running on Express.JS, others on Hapi.JS and others with no framework at all (apps meant to be simple).

**How can I create a "container" Node app** that could redirect the user to each app so that:

- **app_container:3000/app_a/** would be processed as **app_a:8000/**
- **app_container:3000/app_b/** would be processed as **app_b:8001/**
- **app_container:3000/app_c/** would be processed as **app_c:8002/**

And would also be able process request so that:

- **app_container:3000/app_a/get/user** would be processed as **app_b:8000/get/user**
- **app_container:3000/app_b/get?q=valu**e would be processed as **app_b:8000/get?q=value**

Note that the user must always see only the **app_container:3000** URL on its browser.

Comment: What you are describing is a 'reverse proxy', it might be easier to use something like nginx to do this rather than trying to program it yourself in node

Comment: Yeah, I'd second the notion of using nginx for this.  With no programming and just a little config file, you can do this just fine and have a well tested solution.